# MIN INDEX Excel Formula - Where "IF" is a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Just trying to find a simple way of making a formula to give the value of a MIN date found in Row N, if the same column in Row S equals "Outstanding"

Unfortunately, I can't add an image of the table...

N - - - - - - - - - - - - - S

Received - - - - - - - Status

01/01/2013

01/02/2013

01/03/2013 - - - - - Outstanding

01/04/2013 - - - - - Outstanding

01/05/2013 - - - - - Outstanding

01/06/2013 - - - - - Outstanding

01/07/2013

So for example, I'd want the value at the end to be "01/03/2013" - As this is the oldest date where it is "Outstanding" - I've been trying to work out something between IF INDEX with MIN, but to no success!

NOTE: All dates above are in dd/mm/yyyy Format, to save any confusion! Haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind an array function (the first one that came to my mind), you can use this:

```
=MIN(IF(S2:S8="Outstanding",N2:N8))
```

And change the height of the ranges accordingly.

Since this is an array function, **you have to use** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work, instead of enter, after typing the formula.

Comment: +1 - This worked perfectly, thank you - Exactly what I needed! Mudkip props.